# Razor App - Posting Values Captured in UI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a problem with my Web App (Razor Pages)
The aim is to return a list of Skills (aka Capabilities) , display on screen then capture a score for each skill before posting back through a WEB API to a DB via a Web Api..

My View:

```
@page
@model CBSSkillsTracker_WebUI.Pages.ScoreSubmissionFormModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Score Submission Form";
}

<h1>Score Submission Form</h1>


<form method="post">


    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">
                    Capability ID
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    Capability Name
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    Score
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for (int index = 0; index < Model.CapabilitiesList.Count; index++)
            {
                <tr>

                    <td width="10%">
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CapabilitiesList[index].Id)
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.CapabilitiesList[index].Id)
                    </td>
                    <td width="80%">

                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CapabilitiesList[index].CapabilityName)
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.CapabilitiesList[index].CapabilityName)
                    </td>
                    <td width="10%">
                        <input type="number" asp-for="Scores[index].Score" min="0" max="5" step="1" name="txtScore" />
                    </td>


                </tr>
            }


        </tbody>
    </table>

    <button type="submit">submit</button>

</form>
```

My Code Behind \ View Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CBSSkillsTracker_WebUI.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;

namespace CBSSkillsTracker_WebUI.Pages
{
    public class ScoreSubmissionFormModel : PageModel
    {

        string Baseurl = "https://XXXXX.XXXXXX.net";


        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public List<CapabilitiesModel> CapabilitiesList { get; set; }
        
      
        [BindProperty] 
        public List<ScoreModel> Scores { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
        {

           

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                //Passing service base url
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                //Define request data format
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                //Sending request to find web api REST service resource using HttpClient
                HttpResponseMessage Res =  await client.GetAsync("/api/Capabilities");
                //Checking the response is successful or not which is sent using HttpClient
                if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    //Storing the response details recieved from web api
                    var UserResponse = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    //Deserializing the response recieved from web api and storing into the Employee list
                    CapabilitiesList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CapabilitiesModel>>(UserResponse);
                }
              
            }
            return Page();
        }


        public IActionResult OnPost(List<ScoreModel> Scores) 
        {

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {


                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return Page();
                }

                List<ScoreModel> scores = Scores.Select(s => new ScoreModel
                        {
                        Capability = s.Id,
                        Score  = s.Score,
                        })
                    .ToList();


                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl + "/api/Scores");


                //HTTP POST
                var httpContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(scores), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var postTask = client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress.ToString(), httpContent);
                postTask.Wait();

                var result = postTask.Result;
                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return Page();
                }
                else
                { //ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "An Error Occured in 'public ActionResult NewCapability'- Please contact Dev Support ");
                }
            }



            return RedirectToPage ("/Index");


        }

    }
}
```

My models:

```
    namespace CBSSkillsTracker_WebUI.Models
{
    public class CapabilitiesModel
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Category { get; set; }
        public string CapabilityName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }



    }
}
```

And

```
namespace CBSSkillsTracker_WebUI.Models
{
    public class ScoreModel
    {


        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int User { get; set; }
        public int SubmissionPeriod { get; set; }
        public int Capability { get; set; }
        public byte Score { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I have an error on the following line of code:

```
 <input type="number" asp-for="Scores[index].Score" min="0" max="5" step="1" name="txtScore" />
```

The error is : System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

I think its because the Scores model isnt populated or initialised within the OnGet - because until the user populates the score there are no values to bring back, update before posting.

If I remove that line of code the UI populates correctly with the list of Skills but of course there is no way to capture the scores the user enters for posting..

Can anyone help please? Sorry im new to this so any advice\code welcome

Comment: I think it should be List<string> txtscore  in your onpost method....

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean here??

Answer (score 0):

You can try to initialize `Scores` like this,setting `Scores` if `CapabilitiesList` is not null in `OnGet`:

```
public class ScoreSubmissionFormModel : PageModel
    {

        string Baseurl = "https://XXXXX.XXXXXX.net";


        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public List<CapabilitiesModel> CapabilitiesList { get; set; }
        
      
        [BindProperty] 
        public List<ScoreModel> Scores { get; set; }= new List<ScoreModel>();

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
        {

           

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                //Passing service base url
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                //Define request data format
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                //Sending request to find web api REST service resource using HttpClient
                HttpResponseMessage Res =  await client.GetAsync("/api/Capabilities");
                //Checking the response is successful or not which is sent using HttpClient
                if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    //Storing the response details recieved from web api
                    var UserResponse = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    //Deserializing the response recieved from web api and storing into the Employee list
                    CapabilitiesList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CapabilitiesModel>>(UserResponse);
                    foreach (var item in CapabilitiesList) {
                        Scores.Add(new ScoreModel());
                    }
                }
              
            }
            return Page();
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately then once the Post method is called the Scores object passed in is empty..